# Planning CI pipeline to build and push docker containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating a pipeline that can be reused to build a docker image and push that image to azure container registry. Below is the tree structure of my repository:

```
───repo
    ├── app1
    │   ├── dir1
    │   ├── dockerfile
    │   ├── file1 
    │   └── file2
    ├── app2
    │   ├── dir1
    │   ├── dockerfile
    │   ├── file1 
    │   └── file2
    ├── app3
    │   ├── dir1
    │   ├── dockerfile
    │   ├── file1 
    │   └── file2
```

How can I plan my ci in a way that when the pipeline runs and if the developer changes file1 in app1 directory then the pipeline knows that it needs to build the image using the dockerfile in app1 directory?

Note: I am building the pipeline in Azure DevOps.

Comment: See possible GitHub Actions implementation here: https://github.com/relizaio/dockerfile-collection (should be easy to make similar in Azure DevOps) and write-up here: https://medium.com/@taleodor/using-monorepo-do-not-rebuild-unchanged-components-in-ci-c386e7c03426

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple PS script that use git to determine which folder was changed, and set a build variable with the project name and `true`:

```
$files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
$temp=$files -split ' '
$count=$temp.Length
Write-Host "Total changed $count files"
For ($i=0; $i -lt $temp.Length; $i++)
{
  $name=$temp[$i]
  Write-Host "this is $name file"
  $project = $name.Split('/')[0]
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$project]true"
}
```

Now, for each project that changed you have a variable with the project name and the value `true`.

So, in the docker build tasks you can use [custom conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). for example - for `app1` step:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['app1'], 'true'))
```